# Music with Hikari

Tags: python, discord

My music bot built with hikari is unable to join. I have copied the code that I had used from discord.py. It worked properly on discord.py but wont work on hikari for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command('join', 'Makes bot join a voice channel')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def join(ctx):
    try:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
        await ctx.respond("I\'m in")
    except:
        await ctx.respond("You need to be connected to a voice channel in order for me to join")


@bot.command
@lightbulb.command('play', 'Plays track in connected voice channel')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def play(ctx, q: str):
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'default_search': 'auto', 'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    voice = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        try:
            info = ydl.extract_info(q, download=False)
            a = info['entries'][0]['formats'][0]['url']
            queue.append(a)
            if voice.is_playing():
                await ctx.respond('I have queued the track')
            else:
                idk = queue[0]
                queue.pop(0)
                voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(idk, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        except:
            info = ydl.extract_info(q, download=False)
            a = info['url']
            queue.append(a)
            if voice.is_playing():
                await ctx.respond('I have queued the track')
            elif len(queue)==0:
                idk = queue[0]
                voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(idk, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
            else:
                idk = queue[0]
                queue.pop(0)
                voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(idk, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

Comment: This code generates any error description? is there more information you can provide for diagnose this code?

Answer (score 1):

Your command implementation is not the way that Lightbulb handles commands. Command arguments are not passed as arguments to the callback function, they are accessed via `ctx.options.your_option_here`.

Reference: [The option decorator](https://hikari-lightbulb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/commands.html#the-option-decorator)

Example command that accepts an argument:

```py
@bot.command
@lightbulb.option("q", "The track to play.")
@lightbulb.command("play", "Plays track in connected voice channel.")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def play(ctx: lightbulb.Context) -> None:
    await ctx.respond(f"The song you want to play is {ctx.options.q}!")
```

Many of the attributes/methods you are using like `ctx.message.guild.voice_client`,  `ctx.message.author.voice.channel`, and `await channel.connect()` just do not exist in Hikari.

You can't transfer your discord.py code over 1:1.Hikari does implement the discord voice API, however you will need to read the [documentation](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari).

Connecting to a voice channel:

```py
await bot.update_voice_state(ctx.guild_id, channel_id)
```

Disconnecting from a voice channel:

```py
await bot.update_voice_state(ctx.guild_id, None)
```